# Ajax request not sending on android cordova

Tags: android, ajax, android-studio, cordova

Ajax request not sending on android studio with cordova. I tried a simple request to google but it does not work either.

> What i already tried : 
>       - Change minSdk to 23  
>       - Add cordova whitelist plugin and permissions for https and http in config.xml 
>       - add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest 
>  
>       - i have nothing in my network profiler but ajax return a timeout error 
>       - Outside my app, my request work

Code

```
$.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: OAUTH2_URL,
                      cache : false,
                      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                       xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth($("#login").val(), $("#pwd").val()));
                      },

                      dataType: 'json',
                      contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                      data: json,
                      timeout: 5000,
                      success: function (data) {
                           etape3(data);
                      },
                      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                           SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
                           navigator.notification.confirm(
                                 'login or password incorrect.',  // message
                                  null,         // callback
                                  'Error',            // title
                                   ['Ok']                  // buttonName
                                       );
                                   }
                      })
```

I don't know what else to do

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have the internet permission in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes i have it in my app manifest but not in my cordovaLib Manifest.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Logcat?

Comment: I fixed it. I changed my dns with 8.8.8.8 emulator internet was blocked

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the solution!